# Add path to Airflows sys-path globally

Tags: airflow

Is there a way that I in airflow (maybe the config-file) can add `/path/to/folder/` as a folder globally?

Right now I have to write

```py
import sys
sys.path += ["/path/to/folder/"]
```

at the top of all my DAGs, which clearly is not very good, in case I change the folder to `/another_path/to/folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are running Airflow. Generally speaking, your DAGs should see the environment variables Airflow sees, I set PYTHON_PATH for example like this all the time.

If you are running it locally, just set from the command line like for any other process:

```
PATH=/some/path/to/append:$PATH [your airflow command]
```

Or if you're running in Docker, you can set it via the command line, docker-compose, or however else you'd like.

Though not directly related, this part of the Airflow docs may help:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables

Comment: So you would set it as enviroment-variables in e.g `.bashrc` or `profiles` ?

Comment: If you are running it locally, yes with a big exception. Provided you want the same path set in the shell. If you want to override the path just for airflow, and are running airflow locally, I'd try calling it like I mentioned.